# Boolean difference with four cutting objects

Tags: modifiers, topology, geometry

I'm modeling an SNES contoller.

[image]

I don't know how to boolean the controller without creating distorted (unusable) geometry. Here's my blend file.

https://pasteall.org/blend/5706d405f1604f9699fd52a4c33c1260

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. I'm on Blender 2.92.

Comment: So what are you trying to use as the boolean objects and what are you trying to cut out? At the moment you don't have any modifiers in your blend file

Comment: Incidentally using those top objects to boolean the bottom one works fine if you apply the bevel and subdiv modifiers first.